# Promise not resolved even when the request is done

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that returns a promise from an HTTP Request:

```
getToken(id: string): Promise<string> {
    return this.service
      .getToken(id)
      .pipe(
        take(1)
        //catchError(() => of(null))
      )
      .toPromise();
}
```

And I want to know if the call failed (I won't have any token in this case), but the promise doesn't seem to complete because the IF statement is never reached if an error has occurred (BadRequest, Forbidden, etc.)

```
...
const token = await this.getToken(id);

if (!token) {
   console.log('no token');
}
...
```

But if I'm using `catchError(() => of(null))`, the promise completes even if the call failed and I can't understand the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the `take(1)` is for the success path only.

Try this with no catchError:

```
let token;
try {
  token = await this.getToken(id);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}

if (!token) {
 console.log('no token');
}
```

The try catch block should catch the error from the promise and proceed to the `if(!token)`.

Comment: The endpoint is not throwing an error but returns an IActionResult. First time I tried with a try-catch block but the error is not caught.

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming that your `service` is using the angular `HttpClient` inside. As the Observables of the `HttpClient` will always return only one single result and complete after that, I don't get the reason you should need to use `take(1)`. just do:

```
getToken(id: string): Promise<string> {
  return this.service.getToken(id).toPromise();
}
```

The more angular (or rxjs) way would be to subscribe to the Observable or to transform that observable with `pipe(map(data => doSomethingWithData(data))` and then subscribe to it, instead of converting it to a promise and wait for it to resolve.
Checkout the rxjs operators to manipulate observables. Most important are: `map`,`tap`,`switchMap`,`mergeMap`,...

Comment: That's the way promises work. They can either resolve with (or without) a value, or reject with an error, which will throw an exception if you `await` that promise. That's what @AliF50s answer is about.